# Bootstrap data-trigger="focus" doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap popover defined on an icon which works fine if I do not have data-trigger="focus" as part of its definition.  When I include that, the popover does not display when I click the icon.  Here's the code without the data-trigger.

```
<a data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-title="Membership history for Fred Smith" data-html="true" data-content="<table><thead><tr><th class='col-md-2 text-left'>Renewed</th><th>Expiration</th><th>Type</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>12/09/2016</td><td>12/31/2017</td><td>1-Year Individual</td></tr></tbody></table>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:grey;"></span></a>
```

And the code including the data-trigger:

```
<a data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-trigger="focus" data-title="Membership history for Fred Smith" data-html="true" data-content="<table><thead><tr><th class='col-md-2 text-left'>Renewed</th><th>Expiration</th><th>Type</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>12/09/2016</td><td>12/31/2017</td><td>1-Year Individual</td></tr></tbody></table>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:grey;"></span></a>
```

I should also mention that the icon is within a table cell.

Any ideas?

Comment: Per my question, the popover works without the data-trigger and does not open with the data-trigger.  Also, per the code I included, this is not a button.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To use `data-trigger="focus"` attribute on bootstrap popover you need to use `tabindex="0"`.
like this -- (edited to change tab-index to tabindex)

```
<a tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-trigger="focus" data-title="Membership history for Fred Smith" data-html="true" data-content="<table><thead><tr><th class='col-md-2 text-left'>Renewed</th><th>Expiration</th><th>Type</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>12/09/2016</td><td>12/31/2017</td><td>1-Year Individual</td></tr></tbody></table>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:grey;"></span></a>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I haven't seen that documented anywhere but I tried it and the popover still doesn't open

Comment: I did find the docs on this, thanks.  I have it working now, it should be tabindex, not tab-index.  Edited your example code to show that and marked it as the correct answer. Follow up - it appears my edit to show the correction has to be peer reviewed so it may or may not show up eventually.

Answer (score 8):

"**data-trigger=“focus”** doesn't work, was happened when you are using popover in anchors or spans.
*(data-trigger=“focus” properly works when you use the popover for button).*

So in this case you have to add **tabindex="-1"** or **tabindex="0"** for anchor tag or spans tags.

- **tabindex="0"**   appears with a boarder
- **tabindex="-1"**  appears without a boarder

Eg.   `<a data-toggle="popover" tabindex="-1" data-trigger="focus"> Click here</a>`